# Why does GLib redefine types?

Tags: c, types, glib

What is the reasoning behind types to be redefined in GLib? Why do they turn `char` into `gchar`, `int` into `gint`, etc.?

Comment: See also: [Why is it better to use Glib data types (e.g. `gint` instead of `int`)?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13821850/4561887)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Check out [Basic Types](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-Basic-Types.html) in the GLib documentation. Essentially, it's to guarantee that certain types will exist with certain semantics, regardless of which C compiler or platform you're using. The types that C guarantees anyway are `typedef`ed just to make all of the type names look uniform.

Comment: So the reason to turn char into gchar is to make it look prettier?

Comment: In a way, but mainly because int for example may not be the same on all systems, gint8 will always be 8 bits however.

Comment: I guess. Some of the gtypes (arguably) give extra semantics over a simple type, but I think the rest are just for consistency and portability. Also remember that GLib dates from 1999, predating the widespread availability of types like `uint64_t`, which is why they roll their own.

Answer (score 0):

See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13821850/4561887).

Essentially, it's because glib's standard-width types such as [`guint32`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/gstreamer-sdk/data/docs/latest/glib/glib-Basic-Types.html#guint32) predate the C99 and later standard-width types, such as `uint32_t`, which now exists ([as of C99 and later](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/integer)) and is exactly equivalent.

So, glib's `g`-prefixed types are now essentially obsolete. Use the [standardized fixed-width types like `uint32_t`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/integer) now instead.