# What is the purpose of using glib typedefs (gint etc)?

Tags: c, glib

**EDIT:** I'm specifically asking about the non-fixed size types, not the fixed-size types. As stated, I understand the (historical) purpose for using them.

In my current codebase I commonly see Glib types like gint, guint, gboolean, gpointer etc.

Looking in the header file they are just new names for the standard C types:

```
typedef char   gchar;
typedef short  gshort;
typedef long   glong;
typedef int    gint;
typedef gint   gboolean;
typedef void* gpointer;
```

What is the purpose of using these typedefs? It seems to me we are just hiding information, especially in the case of gpointer which is typedeffed to a non-pointer signature. Also gboolean which is used instead of the C standard booleans from C99 (_Bool is defined as a one-byte type, not as int in e.g. the AMD64 Sys V ABI and ARMv7 ABI).

I understand the purpose of fixed-width typedefs before we had **stdint** and perhaps also gboolean before there was **stdbool** but is there any real benefit of using these types in 2015?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is it better to use Glib data types (e.g. \`gint\` instead of \`int\`)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13821332/why-is-it-better-to-use-glib-data-types-e-g-gint-instead-of-int)

Comment: Historical portability reasons. (Before C99 was standardized)

Comment: @MohitJain That's a similar question but IMO it was not fully answered.

Comment: @MohitJain Namely, the answers all concern the fixed-size types which is not what I'm asking about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They were only introduced for consistency and there's no reason to use them.  See [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2800310/converting-an-array-of-characters-to-a-const-gchar/2800318#comment5700249_2800318) from Havoc Pennington (DBus and GNOME developer).

Comment: Thanks, supspected this was the case but wanted to check if I'd missed something.