# Type conversion between Glib types (e.g. guint) to standard C data types (e.g. int)

Tags: c, type-conversion, glib

I am working with a C code base that uses an API function (https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-Hash-Tables.html#g-hash-table-size) that returns a guint. I needed to pass this along downstream as an int. I am wondering if there's any way to do this?

I searched the docs and Google but came up empty.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [converting an array of characters to a const gchar\*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2800310/converting-an-array-of-characters-to-a-const-gchar)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The mere existence of these typedefs baffles me. Check `glib/gtypes.h`:

```
typedef char   gchar;
typedef short  gshort;
typedef long   glong;
typedef int    gint;
typedef gint   gboolean;

typedef unsigned char   guchar;
typedef unsigned short  gushort;
typedef unsigned long   gulong;
typedef unsigned int    guint;
```

So no conversion is needed between `unsigned int` and `guint`, they are the same type.

The usual warnings about converting between `unsigned int` and `int` apply.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1819561/why-does-glib-redefine-types?rq=1#comment1709760_1819582 is the most likely-sounding guess I've seen as to why this is

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1819561/why-does-glib-redefine-types?rq=1#comment1709760_1819582 is not a guess, it’s a correct fact.

Comment: That other SO article might be an explanation for the existence of `gint32` and similar; but so far as I can tell `gint` is a platform-defined `int` on all platforms; similarly other types without specific sizes. So what purpose do they serve? The existence of `gint`, `gchar`, etc., always struck me as an affectation.

Comment: Once they had a dozen types like `gint32` I think it was honestly just done for consistency. Fast forward a few decades its a little annoying but it isn't like `gint32` and friends can be dropped without breaking API.